# Relación entre tablas MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una duda: Sé que relacionar tablas en MySQL con PHPMyAdmin optimiza el rendimiento de las consultas, pero:

¿Cómo se refleja esto a la hora de hacer unos JOIN a mi BD desde mi código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No confundas una herramienta de administración (como PHPMyAdmin o MySQL Workbench, o Toad) con el servidor de base de datos (en este caso, MySQL) ni con el *front-end*:

- PHPMyAdmin sirve para realizar tareas administrativas en el servidor de base de datos.
- El servidor de base de datos es el encargado de procesar los datos.
- El *front-end* es la aplicación que utilizará los datos. Este *front-end* (la "cara visible" a los usuarios) puede ser una aplicación web escrita en PHP, un programa en Java o Python, etcétera.

Es en la carga de trabajo del servidor (MySQL) donde se ve el verdadero beneficio de un correcto diseño de las bases de datos:

1. Una base de datos bien diseñada (normalizada) permite almacenar de forma óptima los datos, evitando duplicidades y redundancias que generen problemas posteriormente, y facilitando la inserción, actualización y consulta de datos.
2. Un buen diseño de tablas y la creación de los índices necesarios acelera la recuperación de datos, lo cual se hace visible en un mejor rendimiento de las aplicaciones que utilizan esos datos.
3. El uso correcto de relaciones permite que los datos se almacenen de forma lógica, consistente y ordenada en tu base de datos, facilitando la explotación de los mismos y su reutilización en todos los proyectos que los utilicen.

Comment: Mejor respuesta no pude recibir, gracias por la ilustración.

Answer (score 1):

Las consultas siempre se ejecutan en la base de datos, no importa si las ejecutas en la linea de comandos de la consola de tu Sistema Operativo, si las ejecutas en la consola de un cliente como PHPMyAdmin o MySQL Workbench o si las ejecutas desde tu código PHP con o sin un ORM, siempre al final la ejecución se da en el motor de Base de Datos, asi que optimizar tus relaciones siempre tendrá un efecto positivo en el performance de tu aplicación.

Answer (score 1):

Para mejorar la optimización de las consultas y el desempeño de la base de datos y poder combinar registro de 2 tablas de una manera más eficiente

Answer (score 0):

Mira para optimizar tablas, primero es que tengas primary key, con ellas tus join serán más precisos, luego apoyate en indices  y podrás tener un mejor rendimiento,despues de ello , trata de dejar de lado las subsquery, no sobrecarges las filas con otras consultas , y si es un poco más complejo trata de hacer Procedimientos almacenados.

Answer (score 0):

El impacto real se refleja cuando una BD posee miles de registros y es atacada con cientos de consultas por segundo, imagina que tu BD es una casa, sea como sea que ordenes tus cosas dentro de la casa, si solo entras tu a buscar algo siempre te demoraras poco, ahora imagina que miles de personas quieren entrar al mismo tiempo a buscar algo. es pensando en ello que una base de datos debe estar bien construida y normalizada.